# Move pixel from one place to another in Julia

Tags: image, julia

I was curious how would I move pixel with particular coordinates to another location? Or in other word, change the locations of pixels in the image? And then output the changed image again.

```
using Images
img_lab = rand(Lab, 10, 10)
```

[image: output]

For example pixel in (1,1) move to (2,3) and overwrite the existing pixel.

Later I want to implement this idea to real images and to all pixels in the image.

Comment: Do you mean like `img_lab[2,3] = img_lab[1,1]`? The image is just a matrix, and you manipulate its elements the same way.

Comment: oops, did not think of that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
img_lab[2,3] = img_lab[1,1]
```

The image is just a matrix, and you manipulate its elements the same way.

Comment: Otherwise there will be notifications on all Julia forums that this hasn't been answered... 